# Magento 2.1.2 : how to trigger UI Component onUpdate() on load

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I currently have a UI Component (which extends the default select-component), and I want to do something when the select changes it's value. So I use the `onUpdate()`-method to hook into this:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function (_, SelectComponent) {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Manipulate the default select component
   */
  return SelectComponent.extend({
    /**
     * Method fired when a different option is picked
     */
    onUpdate: function () {
      this._super();

      // do stuff here 

      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now, when creating new entities the `onUpdate()` is triggered. When I change values the `onUpdate()` is triggered. But as soon as I have an already existing entity the `onUpdate()`-method is not triggered on page load.

Anyone knows what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly you have added a function to `onUpdate` which works fine, but it isn't working on page load?

If this is the case then it's because you have only informed the browser so run your code when a change occurs, if you want it to happen on page load you'll also need to do it on initialisation like so:

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();

    // Your code here

    return this;
},
```

And your code isn't waiting for page load, if you want this to happen you need to add `domReady!` as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried `initialize`, but the DOM is not ready at that moment. But now you've told me about the `domReady!` dependency that might just be the answer to my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the onUpdate function on initialization, like below:

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();

    // trigger onUpdate on initialization
    this.onUpdate(this.value());

    return this;
},
```

PS: I do not have the reputation to add comments on the above answer.